# Asp.net Core API with CORS on Service Fabric 100% CPU bottleneck

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.net Core on **.Net Framework 4.5.2** hosted on Service Fabric as **STATELESS** Service.

The API is a vanilla API, empty

```
 [Route("Test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Done");
    }
}
```

This is my Startup Code

```
  public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.AddResponseCompression();

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
        {
            // Force Camel Case to JSON
            opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });

    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

This is the OpenAsync method:

```
  Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);
            string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}";

            //.UseWebListener()
            _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                           .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                           .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                           .Build();

            _webHost.Start();

            return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
        }
```

Everything plain and simple, no customizations.
The CORS call works, everything is perfect.
I did a test using Visual Studio Team Services with **15K users load**, and it all worked like a charm, with 14K RPS. **I think the Load test from VS do not use the CORS middleware by the way.**

Now the problem is that when I put this exactly **empty API** in production, receiving calls from around just **100 simultaneous users**, the CPU jump to 100% in 3 minutes. The calls are answered until the CPU reach 100% and then start sending errors back.
Seems that with 15000 users and NO CORS it all WORKS, and with 100 users + CORS DOES NOT WORK, CPU goes to 100% and remain like that **until I reboot the VM Scale set.**

[image: CPU]

If I stop sending calls, the CPU of the 5 nodes remains stable at 99% without receiving any single call.

**How is this possible?**
I tried everything, the project is plain and simple, the VS load test works, it's only when I put this on real CORS calls from different sites and different IP addresses that this happens.

I did a performance Trace in the server before sending traffic to it, again with a load test from Visual studio using EXACTLY the CORS headers everything is blazing fast.

With Real world calls this is what I see in the profiler:

[image: Trace]

There is nothing in it but the CORS middleware and the usual Kestrel processes.
The Stateless service eat up 99% of the CPU, **and keep it even if I STOP the Traffic.**

This is another 30 seconds trace with no traffic coming but CPU at 90%

[image]

I don't know what else to do, there is something wrong with CORS, I'm sure of it, even if it works, somehow something goes wrong.

This is a CORS call, correctly served.

[image: cors call]

**Is there a bug in the Asp.net Core CORS middleware?**

**UPDATE:**

I tried many combinations to isolate the problem:

1. New cluster, same Asp.net Core vanilla service=> Problem still there
2. Same cluster new project same Asp.net Core vanilla service=> Problem still there
3. Same Cluster WebAPI OWIN service, same code => **Problem VANISHED!**

The problem occurs with Asp.Net Core on Service Fabric using CORS with more than 50 concurrent requests.

This is the CPU (0.85%) with a Asp.Net Stateless service using Visual Studio template, OWIN and CORS, with around 100 concurrent connections and the same empty web API above

[image: OWIN]

At this point I need help from a Microsoft official source to address the problem.
I'm almost sure this is a **Asp.net Core CORS bug**, that happens when you host it on Service Fabric as a stateless service and send it some minimum traffic (not just a couple of refresh in the browser).

Comment: I'd recommend posting this issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues

Comment: Interesting.. let us know what you find out. Is it perhaps a Kestrel issue? I see IIS 8.5 in the response headers so I'm assuming you're doing a reverse proxy?